# Can I have an Express middleware that runs after the router but before the route handler?

Tags: node.js, express

I want a generic middleware that can take the "req.route.path" value (e.g. "/foo/:id" and not the actual URL value "/foo/123") and return it on a HTTP response header called "X-ROUTE-NAME". The idea is for this route value to be recorded and logged by separate logging/metrics infrastructure and allow "group by" on the route name for other analysis purposes later.

Here's my first attempt:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  const {path} = req.route;
  console.log("The path was:", path);
  res.setHeader("X-ROUTE-NAME", req.route.path);
  next();
});
```

It doesn't work because if you put it BEFORE you register routes, it doesn't have any value in `req.route.path` yet. But if you register it AFTER the routes, you get an exception when you try to set the header if a handler has already sent content on the `req`.

So yah, the tricky part is figuring out how to snatch the "req.route.path" value AFTER it's set by the router (and saving it to the response as a header), but BEFORE a handler picks it up (since the handler can send content if it wants to and then you wont be able to set headers anymore).

Any ideas?

Comment: What routers.middleware is responsible for adding `req,route`? Can you show how you register them?

Comment: I’m using express.Router. So something like: `const router = express.Router(); router.get(“/foo/:fooId”, someHandler);`. The key here is that I want to publish this as a shared middleware library within my company.

Comment: Ok, can you add code where you register all routers and indicate where you need your middleware?

Comment: Imagine multiple `router.get` calls like above, and I want a single middleware to add the required header regardless of which route was resolved.

Comment: `router.use(yourMiddleWare)` does not work too? What about `router.get(“/foo/:fooId”, yourMiddleware, someHandler);`?

Comment: No, you cannot.  You will only get the `req.route.path` you want when you are INSIDE the actual route handler that matched the pattern you specified.  You will need some prefix code that runs at the beginning of every route handler because that's the only place you get the value you want.   Middleware supplies its own URL match pattern so if you use some common milddleware you won't get the pattern from whatever route will eventually match, you will get the pattern from your middleware (not what you want).

Comment: You could setup the middleware after the route handler, but your dont send the response there. Just put your response together inside the route handler, call in the route handler next, use after the route handler your middleware, and after that, another "middleware" that sends the respose to the client. Like a "catch all" handler or "error" middleware: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers

Comment: Thx! The main problem is we want to ship this as something people can easily add to existing applications without re-writing their routes or handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me:

```
// create a test router and handler
const testRouter = express.Router();

testRouter.get('/test/:testId', (req, res) => {
  console.log("HANDLER");
  res.send("{}")
});

// create a function that injects a "beforeHandle" function into a router instance (depends on a private interface though)
function onBeforeHandle(router: IRouter, beforeHandle: (req: Request, res: Response) => void) {
  const methodName = "process_params";
  const routerAny: any = router;
  const oldFn = routerAny[methodName];
  
  if (!oldFn) {
    throw new Error(`No private '${methodName}' method found on router. This may be an incompatible version of Express.`);
  }
  
  if (oldFn.length !== 5) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid number of arguments on private '${methodName}' method. This may be an incompatible version of Express.`);
  }

  const newFn = (...args: any[]) => {
    const [, , req, res, handler] = args;

    beforeHandle(req, res);
    return oldFn.apply(routerAny, args as any);
  }
  routerAny[methodName] = newFn;
}

// function to be executed prior to the route handler
function setRouteNameHeader(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const routeHeaderName = "Q-ROUTE-NAME";
  if (!req.route) {
    console.log(`Can't add '${routeHeaderName}' header as 'req.route' is not set.`);
  } else {
    if (!res.headersSent) {
      res.setHeader(routeHeaderName, req.route.path);
    } else {
      console.log(`Can't add '${routeHeaderName} ${req.route.path}' header as headers were already sent.`);
    }
  }
}

// actually inject the function
onBeforeHandle(testRouter, setRouteNameHeader);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this :

**router.use(routerModule)** to route to the router module in main file.
And use **router.get('/path', yourroute, actualCodeToBeExecuted)** in the router module.

In this way, your **yourroute** be called after the router but before the actual **functional route**.

Hope this works!

Comment: What do "routerModule" and "yourroute" represent?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  const {path} = req.route;
  console.log("The path was:", path);
  
  next();
  res.setHeader("X-ROUTE-NAME", req.route.path);
});
```

moving the setHeader should help